# How to get All items associated to a user in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection of Items that a particular make and perform a transaction.  In my schema, I associate the userId to each item.  I want to be able to display as a list all the items that the user owns.

Here I have managed to total up all sizes of each item but I cant work out a way how to get a total for each user

```
  {
    id: Number,
    x: Number,
    y: Number,
    xSize: String,
    ySize: String,
    imageSource: String,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    website: String,

  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

  Item.find({}, function (err, items) {
    var itemMap = {};
    items.forEach(function (item) {
      itemMap[item._id] = item;
    });
    var countedNames = items.reduce(function (allNames, name) {
      if (name.xSize in allNames) {
        allNames[name.xSize]++;
      }
      else {
        allNames[name.xSize] = 1;
      }
      return allNames;
    }, {});
```

Essentially i want to get a list basically saying 
{name:"Dave", website:"www.google.com, items:[item1, item2]}

where item1 and item2 relate to the item schema

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your `UserSchema` to contain a reference to the item, in this format:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    website: String,
    items: 
    [{
       item: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}
    }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

This will simply allow you to perform the following query:

```
User.find({}).populate('Item')
```

Which would return the `User` document, and all items associated under the document.

You could do the following:

```
let users = User
    .find({})
    .populate('Item')
    .exec(function (err, users) {
       if (err) { console.log(err); }
       console.log(users)
    }
```

Rewriting the schema will make querying users for their items much easier.